# anabelian analogues of the Weil Pairing?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Classically the Weil pairing for an abelian variety $A$ over a field $k$ (say of characteristic 0 for simplicity) can be thought of as an (especially nice) morphism of galois modules:

$$\pi_1(A_{\overline{k}})\times\pi_1(A_{\overline{k}})\rightarrow\mu_\infty$$

where $\pi_1(A_{\overline{k}})$ is the etale fundamental group of $A_{\overline{k}}$.

I hope this question makes sense, but 
**my vague question is:**

If $X$ is some anabelian curve over $k$ (either genus 0 with $\ge 3$ punctures, genus 1 with $\ge 1$ puncture, or genus $\ge 2$), then do there exist interesting examples of $G_k$-groups $G$ (here I'm thinking that $G$ is a pro-etale group scheme over $k$, equivalently a profinite group with an action of $G_k$), and a morphism of $G_k$-groups

$$(\cdot,\cdot) : \pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})\times\pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})\rightarrow G$$

Here I'm either viewing $\pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})$ as being an outer representation of $G_k$, or being a legit $G_k$-module (if $X$ admits any $k$-rational points).

By "morphism" I either mean a homomorphism, or a "bilinear" map (ie, $(ab,c) = (a,c)(b,c)$ and $(a,bc) = (a,b)(a,c)$), or an equivalence class of such morphisms.

Thus if we consider $\pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})$ as being an "outer $G_k$-module", then by "morphism" I would have to mean equivalence classes of morphisms modulo conjugation in $G$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes I'm sorry I meant to reply thanking you for pointing out my mistake, but I couldn't decide what to say about your point about the albanese morphism, so I never finished the response.

Comment: I think the Weil pairing goes from $\pi _1(A_{\bar{k}})\times \pi _1(\hat{A}_{\bar{k}})$ to $\mu_{\infty}$.